# Is DSL digital or analogue?

Tags: networking, router, internet, adsl

I've looked all over forums and this looks like a popular debate. I currently have an ADSL Sky Broadband connection through the old copper phone line, needing a microfilter to split the frequency bands. Is the broadband connection digital or analogue? Voice is certainly analogue and I would of thought you wouldn't be able to have both digital and analogue on the exact same line. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is a bit of a tricky one. I'll look more into it later but take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line_access_multiplexer) to see if it answers some questions. I always thought the point of your modem was to translate analog into digital and vice versa. But according to that article, that is not quite how it works

Comment: http://techterms.com/definition/dsl

Comment: The copper transmits analog signals. Then a modem (**mo**dulator/ **de**modulator) converts the part of the spectrum that the splitter removes from the voice line into a digital signal. This happened with the whole spectrum with old modems, and with its upper part with DSL modems.

Answer (score 7):

> Is DSL digital or analogue?

The various flavors of xDSL, or Digital Subscriber Line, all employ sophisticated digital signal processing to transmit digital information over twisted-pair wires.
Such signals are simply called "digital" signals for convenience.
However this is an analog world (unless you're studing sub-atomic particles, where quantum physics take over).

A *"digital signal"* is a misnomer; it really means digital information conveyed by an analog waveform.
All waveforms have continuous rather than discrete values, and are therefore analog.  A waveform cannot be at one discrete voltage level, and then instantly change to another discrete voltage level.  A digital signal would only have two levels, e.g. `0` and `1`.  A state of `1/2` is never permitted.  But it's impossible to generate such a signal in this analog world.

Typically a combination of amplitude, phase, and frequency are employed to modulate digital information into an analog waveform.
The simplest "digital" signal, the logic signal (e.g. as used in TTL), uses just amplitude modulation to represent logic levels/states `0` and `1`.  The logic states are represented by, not specific voltage levels as you would expect for a true digital values, but, as a concession to the analog world that the signal has to operate in, voltage ranges (i.e. a continuum) for each logic state.

Every logic input is a very simple analog-to-digital converter.  When the input is sampled (triggered by a clock signal), a sampled voltage in the low-voltage range is interpreted as logic `0`.  But if the sampled voltage is in the high-voltage range, then a logic `1` is "read".  All of this analog-to-digital conversion is simply treated as as logic or digital input, and textbooks always use perfect square pulses to represent changes in logic states.

ADSL uses both phase and amplitude modulation to transmit digital information as an analog signal.

> I would of thought you wouldn't be able to have both digital and analogue on the exact same line.

Whether a cable/wire/channel can carry more than one signal depends on the signals themselves.
"Digital" signals can time multiplex (using data frames) so that the medium can be shared; that's how several users can share a single ISP connection to the Internet.  But a pure analog signal (e.g. AM radio) is continuous in time, so time multiplexing is not possible.

Frequency-division multiplexing can be employed for (analog) signals to share a medium.  The (open space) electromagnetic spectrum is divided up into television, radio and communication bands and channels.  Channels are used for analog or "digital" signals.

In the case of ADSL, the voice signal is restricted to 0 to 4 KHertz.  The ADSL signal (which is modulated to carrier frequencies > 4KHz) is given the rest of the bandwidth of the twisted-pair cable.
Note that the common "digital" logic signal (e.g. TTL) uses simple amplitude moulation, and is full bandwidth.  (Use Fourier analysis to convert pulses and square waves to sine waves to determine frequency content.)  So logic signals are not suitable for frequency-division multiplexing.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are good, but complex.  Here is a simple one.

ADSL is using an analog carrier to encode a digital signal.   AN ADSL device includes a Modem (but a much faster and more complex one then the old dial-up ones) - the input to the modem on the sending side is digital, the modem converts it to analog, the remote side converts it back to digital.

As far as the splitter goes - think of a modem like a radio.  The bottom most frequency (in the case of ADSL its a little over 0 - 64k) is split off by the splitter so it acts like a regular phone line.   The ADSL Modem contains the equivalent of a large number of receivers, such that it can send and receive multiple stations simultaneously on the higher frequencies (and one of the reasons speeds differ is some frequencies will work better then others depending on the line) - each of these frequencies requires the digital signal is imposed on a carrier - modulating and turning it to analog, and then the reverse on the other side.

Answer (score -1):

Generally when you refer to ADSL. As the acronym states it is called Asymmetric Digital Subscriber Line. Which would makes DSL a digital connection. It is quite funny that your voice service uses the same network as your ADSL but one is Digital and the other Analogue. But in the end DSL is digital.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted this because its technically incorrect.  Yes, D does stand for "digital", but an ADSL connection is not actually digital - the signal going across the wires is not 0's and 1's, and a DSL device has a modem to modulate and demodulate it.

Answer (score -2):

Although my maternal language is *not* English I am pretty good at it, so here it goes:
Digital Subscriber Line could mean:
**a.** Digital Line for a (digital) Subscriber
**b.** (Analog) Line for a Digital Subscriber
So **b** solves all dilemmas!
By the way [the fad at the time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line#History) of introduction (1988) was ISDN which is digital *and advertised as such*, so that new tech being analog would be counter-marketing, so the naming ambiguity could be purposeful...